# Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/modules/mod_dav_svn

Tags: apache2

am using Apache 2.4.1 on windows 7 & svn 1.7.4 Repository.

whwn i trying load module mod_dav_svn in httpd.conf.

It shows error

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 172 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.4/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.

mod_dav_svn.so is already there in Module folder and libapr-1.dll,intl3_svn.dll also available in bin directory.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That error is usually because the modules and the apache version don't jive. It's possible that the version of SVN isn't built for apache 2.4. Try grabbing a set built for apache 2.4 from here: http://alagazam.net/

Comment: Thanks,But i have another problem no when start the Apache2.4 services in the windows Services it shows                                                    Windows could not start the Apache2.4 service on Local Computer.       Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: @user1553605 According to [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html) it says to run it in the console and see what error it gives you.